# How to get the fill value of a style when using a styleFunction?

Tags: openlayers

I have a cluster layer which I styled with a style function. I want to be able to have a color picker in my frame for each vector layer so that I could change the fill value of the style independently for each layer.

When I tried to set the initial value for the color picker to the actual fill color of the layer I noticed that if I use layer.getStyle() I don't get a Style object, but a function!

How could I retrieve the fill value from that? Moreover, how could I adjust that value with a color picker?

**Edit:**
as dvmac01 suggested I am using the `forEachFeature` function to change the style.

```
function changeColor() {
    layer.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature) {
        // this happens when the source is a cluster
        if(feature.get('features')) {
            var resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
            var style = clusterStyle(feature, resolution, this.value);
            feature.setStyle(style);
        } else {
            var style = new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill ({color: this.value})
            });
            feature.setStyle(style);
        }
    }, this);
}
colorPicker.addEventListener('input',changeColor);
```

I try to check whether the current layer is a cluster layer or a regular (polygon) layer. If I change the color of a polygon layer everything works fine. However, for my cluster layer, everything appears to be working fine when I check the styles on the developer console, but for some reason the points are not redrawn with the correct color.

If I type this in the console `map.getLayers().item(2).getSource().getFeatures()[0].getStyle().getImage().getFill();` I can see that the value is the one that I selected with the color picker, yet the circles keep the original color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Since the cluster layer changes dynamically as zoom changes, it is necessary to supply a style function, instead of a static style. What I ended up doing was having a global dictionary storing the fill color for each layer. The color picker modifies the relevant color for the selected layer, and the style function fetches the color from there.

```
var fill_colors = {};
var clusterStyle = function(feature, resolution) {
    var parentLayer = feature.get('features')[0].parentLayer;
    var fill = fill_colors[parentLayer.idCounter];
    var size = feature.get('features').length;

    style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: size === 1 ? 7 : 10,
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#fff'
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: fill
            })
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            text: size === 1 ? '' : size.toString(),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#fff'
            })
        })
    });
    return style;
};


function changeColor() {
    layer.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature) {
        // this happens when the source is a cluster
        if(feature.get('features')) {
            fill_colors[layer.idCounter] = this.value;
        } else {
            var style = new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke ({color: this.value})
            });
            feature.setStyle(style);
        }
    }, this);
}
colorPicker.addEventListener('input',changeColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code it's difficult to answer why layer.getStyle might return a function but the following code works for me. I have several inputs(either pickers or number steppers) and the result of my event listening on these triggers this function:

```
    var drawLayer, style, fillColPickerValue, strokeColPickerValue, strokeWidthValue; // Global variable declared upfront

    function setFillStroke(strokeColPickerValue, strokeWidthValue, fillColPickerValue) {
        drawLayer = session.activeRoute.Layers[0]; // identify the relevant layer

        drawLayer.getSource().forEachFeature(function (feature) {
            fillColPickerValue = $('body, html').find("#fillColPicker").data("kendoColorPicker").value();
            strokeColPickerValue = $('body, html').find("#strokeColPicker").data("kendoColorPicker").value();
            strokeWidthValue = $('body, html').find("#strokeWidth").data("kendoNumericTextBox").value();
            console.log(strokeWidthValue);

            style = new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: fillColPickerValue,
                    opacity: 1.0
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: strokeColPickerValue,
                    width: strokeWidthValue
                })
            });
            feature.setStyle(style);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have tried something similar to that using `forEachFeature` but somehow it is not working. I have edited my original question to show my current code.

Comment: From what I can see, you aren't identifying the layer. In my example:

    drawLayer = session.activeRoute.Layers[0]; // identify the relevant layer
Also, what is your If statement doing? if(feature.get('features')) ? Maybe insert a console.log to see if anything is identified and maybe comment out the If part to see if it's not matching your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Since unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment, I'm posting this as an answer.

As an addition to [dvmac01's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/193159/146286), and of course taking into account that I'm referring to newer versions of Openlayers, when requesting a layer's style via `getStyle` it returns a `StyleLike` object [as per the documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html#getStyle). This means that the style could be a plain `Style` object, a `StyleFunction` or an Array of `Style`. One reason for a layer to have a `StyleFunction` would be that it represents features with a label displaying a property of the feature, another would be having a categorized representation of the layer.

Point is: **when trying to modify the style of a layer you would have to take into account the fact that dealing with a `StyleFunction` differs from dealing with a plain `Style` object and that your application might not know beforehand how was the layer styled.** In addition to this and [as Sofia describes in its answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/193419/146286) a cluster layer might have a `StyleFunction` on top of the style of the layer because it renders different markers depending on how many features are represented by the cluster's marker.

**So, finally, to deal with all of this** I have taken this approach (in which I'm still working):

- Have a class extending the `VectorLayer` and create methods that will return the style for an example feature (not taking a feature from the layer because layer might be empty).
- Have methods in that class that deal with the style of the layer internally, thus encapsulating the logic of dealing with a plain `Style` or a `StyleFunction`.

I was dealing with a `Cluster` so my `VectorLayer` had two styles, one for each single feature and another for when features are clustered.

```typescript
class ClusteredMarkerLayer extends VectorLayer<Cluster> {
  #singleFeatureStyle: SingleFeatureStyle
  #clusterFeatureStyle: ClusterFeatureStyle
  #styleCache: StyleCache

  constructor(
    name: string,
    singleFeatureStyle: SingleFeatureStyle,
    clusterFeatureStyle: ClusterFeatureStyle,
    options: Options
  ) {
    super({
      source: new Cluster(options),
      properties: {
        name: name,
      },
    })

    this.#singleFeatureStyle = singleFeatureStyle
    this.#clusterFeatureStyle = clusterFeatureStyle
    this.#styleCache = {}
    this.styleFunction = this.styleFunction.bind(this)

    this.setStyle(this.styleFunction)
  }

  get getSingleFeatureStyle(): Style | Style[] {
    // INFO: this would be creating a dummy feature of the 
    // layer. Since I am trialing this, I have hard-coded
    // the supossed properties of the feature, but there 
    // must be a better solution
    let f = new Feature({
      properties: {
        name: 'name',
        id: 0,
      },
    })

    if (typeof this.#singleFeatureStyle === 'function') {
      return this.#singleFeatureStyle(f)
    }

    return this.#singleFeatureStyle
  }

  set setSingleFeatureStyle(style: SingleFeatureStyle) {
    this.#singleFeatureStyle = style
  }

  // INFO: example set fill
  setSingleFeatureStyleFill(fill: Fill) {
    // INFO: here the old function gets copied and the Style modified
    if (typeof this.#singleFeatureStyle === 'function') {
      let _s = this.#singleFeatureStyle.bind({})

      let newStyle = (feat: Feature): Style => {
        let s = _s(feat)

        let i = s.getImage()
        
        if (i instanceof CircleStyle) i.setFill(fill)

        return s
      }

      this.#singleFeatureStyle = newStyle
      
      // INFO: trigger layer re-render
      this.changed()
    } else {
      let s = this.#singleFeatureStyle.getImage()
      if (s instanceof CircleStyle) s.setFill(fill)
      this.changed()
    }
  }

  get getClusterFeatureStyle(): ClusterFeatureStyle {
    return this.#clusterFeatureStyle
  }

  set setClusterFeatureStyle(style: ClusterFeatureStyle) {
    this.#clusterFeatureStyle = style
  }

  styleFunction(feature: FeatureLike): Style {
    const size = feature.get('features').length
    if (size === 1) {
      const feat = feature.get('features')[0]

      if (typeof this.#singleFeatureStyle === 'function') {
        return this.#singleFeatureStyle(feat)
      }

      return this.#singleFeatureStyle
    } else {
      if (typeof this.#clusterFeatureStyle === 'function') {
        return this.#clusterFeatureStyle(feature)
      }

      return this.#clusterFeatureStyle
    }
  }
}
```